# How to reference a field of table in CASE... WHEN clause of Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a simple logic to implement in Postgresql db table.
The table name is "spotfire".
So, it has various types of fields (integer, string, Decimal).
What I want is: return value itself if the field is numeric, else return 0.
Here is my query.

```
CASE "%(name)s" ~ '^[0-9\.]+$'
        WHEN true THEN spotfire."%(name)s"
        ELSE 0 
END
```

But I get this error:

> There is an entry for table "spotfire", but it cannot be referenced
>   from this part of the query.

It seems I can't return the value of the field of the table on "THEN" clause. How can I return the value of the field if the field is numeric?
Is this something you can help me?